# Extracting average value at point using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, excel, extract, values

I have a dataset of over 500 points that represent the location of a number of site boundaries and a Tif file displaying the wind speed data over the study area.

Is it possible using ArcGIS Pro to extract the wind speed data at these points?

Additionally would it be possible to take the mean wind speed within a certain distance of the point (or a polygon around a point)?

I know this can be done using the 'Extract Values to Points' tool in ArcGIS, however you need a more advanced license to do this.

Comment: If the raster isnt very big you can convert it to vector format and intersect with your points. (I would Use QGIS and *Sample raster values*)

Comment: extract values from points works at all license levels as indicated in the help file [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm#L_) what you do require is the spatial analyst extension. Have you got that installed, licensed and turned on?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Mean wind speed at a certain distance?  Yes, but again you would need to have a spatial analyst license to run the zonal statistics tool in ArcGIS.  As @BERA points out, without an ArcGIS spatial analyst license you could use QGIS for free.  See this tool. 
 https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice. I used QGIS and Zonal Statistics and it worked.